# Why my MySQL statement doesn't return any records when the where clause with ALL returns true?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have two tables:

```
create table m1 (id int, name varchar(255));
insert into m1 (id, name) values 
 (1, 'tingwei'),
 (2, 'jiahui'),
 (3, 'naidan'),
 (5, 'weizhi'),
 (9, 'siyao');

create table m2 (newid int, name varchar(255));
insert into m2 (newid, name) values 
 (1, 'leijun'),
 (2, 'wangjianlin'),
 (3, 'wangjianlin'),
 (5, 'wangjianlin'),
 (9, 'wangjianlin');
```

And I wanna get all the fields in m1 which meets condition where all values of id in m1 is the same as all values of newid in m2, and this is my code:

```
select * from m1
where id = all (select newid from m2);
```

But I got 0 record returned. All values of id and newid is the same: 1,2,3,5,9. I think where clause should return TRUE. Why?

Comment: That's not what an `ALL` subquery does. You're asking to select m1 rows where the id is equal to all the ids from m2, which is impossible since they're not all the same.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I got something wrong understanding the concept of ALL. May you give me an example code using ALL in this case?

Comment: @ChrisMa I suggest you take a look at the manual page I have linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns no result because it requires that each `id` value in `m1` is the same as **all** the `newid` values in `m2`, and since `1` is not equal to `2`, `3`, `5` or `9` that row is not returned, and the same applies to the other rows. See the manual on [subqueries with all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html).

I think what you actually want is a `JOIN` on `newid`, which will return rows in `m1` whose `id` value exists in `newid` in `m2`:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM m1
JOIN m2 ON m2.newid = m1.id
```

or perhaps an `IN` expression:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM m1
WHERE id IN (SELECT newid FROM m2)
```

Output (for both queries for your sample data):

```
id  name
1   tingwei
2   jiahui
3   naidan
5   weizhi
9   siyao
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oN5fxNrPiBniygzAUdv4xS/1)